# Mount directory from docker container to host

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to mount a directory from a docker container to the host file system

```
sudo mount 172.17.0.2:/mnt/my_storage /home/user/data/
```

but the command seems to be pending.

I used this command in the past with another instance of the same container image and everything was fine.

Any check to face the issue? Is there another way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can't directly edit the files in a running container from the host.  (That specific command implies an NFS server, which your container definitely isn't running.)  Can you say a little more about your larger workflow, and why you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't add a mount during container creation.

#### local folder `/home/user/data/`

```
docker run [..] -v /home/user/data/:/mnt/my_storage [..]
```

#### named volume `app_data`

```
docker run [..] -v app_data:/mnt/my_storage [..]
```

Have a look at: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: What if (a) `/mnt/my_storage` contains several subdirectories A, B and C, (b) I want to mount only A in `app_data` and (c) I don't know in advance the name of the subdirectories (since the container itself acts as a client which synchronizes a remote repo)?

Comment: @Fab I guess you can't use volumes, if you don't know the name of the directory and you don't want to mount the parent directory. Depending on your task you could use `docker cp` to share files between the container and the host, but it's obviously not the same as mounts.

Comment: Yes, I can't use `docker cp` since the two dirs have to be synchronized at any time. What's wrong with using the `mount` command?